# python random word guessing program

Tags: python

I am programming a word guessing game in python but I am having troubles figuring out the algorithms in the guess() function.

The blank (_) is suppose to disappear accordingly when the user guess a correct letter and be replaced by that character. However, there are some still lingering around even the user guessed the correct word. How do I tweak the formatting to make them be replaced by guessed characters?

Another problem is that the program is giving me 10 attempts regardless of if I got the word right or wrong. I am guessing using if statements or for loop with iteration on attempts but I am not sure. How do I make it stop after I have the right word?

Thank you

```
    def pick():
        print()
        f = open('words.txt', 'r')
        wlist = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        chosenword = random.choice(wlist)

        return(chosenword)

    def guess():
        #Determine length of chosen word and display number of blanks
        chosenword = pick()
        pH = '_ ' * (len(chosenword)-1)
        print()
        print (pH)
        print()

        #Number of failed attempts
        attempt = 0
        count = 10
        #Receive guess
        for i in range (0, 10):
            attempt += 1
            guess = input("Enter a letter for a guess : ")
            guess = guess.upper()

        #Check if guess is found in random word
            if guess in chosenword:
                for i in range (0,len(chosenword)):
                    if guess == chosenword[i]:
                        pH = pH[:i] + guess + pH[i+1:]
                print(pH)
            if guess not in chosenword:
                print(pH)
        if pH == chosenword:
            print ("You guessed the word - congrats!")
        else:
            print ("The word was ",chosenword)
            print ("Sorry - bettter luck next time.") 
    guess()
    pick()
```

Comment: One issue is I think you need a "break" to get out of the for loop when the user guesses the correct word.  if pH == chosenword:
            print ("You guessed the word - congrats!") needs to be followed by a break.

Comment: Each unknown character seems to be two characters (underscore and space) which you're replacing with character  pH = '_ ' * (len(chosenword)-1).  Also why are you subtracting one?

Comment: Your last two lines calls guess() followed by pick(). But the guess function calls pick.  Shouldn't you just call guess?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that works using a specified list.  You can change it to read from a file.  I placed comments in the code to show corrections to your code.

```
import random

def pick():
        # You want to change this to load from file
        wlist = ['hello', 'today', 'monday', 'every', 'neighbor']
        chosenword = random.choice(wlist)

        return chosenword

def guess():
    #Determine length of chosen word and display number of blanks
    chosenword = pick().upper()  # Use upper case throughout

    pH = '_' * len(chosenword)    # don't subtract one from length and remove space
    print (pH)

    #Number of failed attempts
    attempt = 0
    count = 10
    #Receive guess
    for i in range (0, 10):
        attempt += 1
        guess = input("Enter a letter for a guess : ")
        guess = guess.upper()

        #Check if guess is found in random word
        if guess in chosenword:
            for i in range (0,len(chosenword)):
                if guess == chosenword[i]:
                    pH = pH[:i] + guess + pH[i+1:]  
            if pH == chosenword:
              break  # need to break from guessing when they have guess the right word
        if guess not in chosenword:
            print(pH)

    if pH == chosenword:
        print ("You guessed the word - congrats!")
        return  # need to break from funtion when they guess the right word
    else:
        print ("The word was ",chosenword)
        print ("Sorry - bettter luck next time.")

guess()
```